# How to recover data from an external hard drive that doesn't show up on Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning, external-hard-drive, lacie

I have a 500GB "LACIE by S+ARCK" external hard drive that although shows as a connected device (even makes the "usb device connected sound"), doesn't show up and can't be accessed by Windows (an empty partition named "EXCHANGE" shows up just fine on a MacBook Pro).

The hard drive is making the regular "working" sound that external hard drives make and so I assume (= want to hope) that it's not dead but just doesn't get recognised, for some reason.

I took it to a repair shop and they told me it's dying but that they could get the data out of it but a few days later they informed me that they were not able in the end.

However, I am not very convinced (= don't want to give up hope) so I am wondering if it's worth to try another repair shop or if, even better, there's another a way to access it and get the data that it contains (copied on the computer or transferred to another hard drive, maybe)?

Comment: Unless it was a very poor shop, then likely they have told you the slim chances and you are looking at a recovery agency if the data is that valuable to you.

Comment: Open the Lacie case and remove the hard drive, then connect the drive using a hard drive to usb adapter, see if the drive can be accessed now.

Comment: Its not possible to be sure on the information you have provided. It is entirely probable that someone with deal recovery knowledge or a data recovery company who charge $$$ would be able to get some data off the drive, assuming that the store you sent it to didn't do something stupid (and I'm concerned they may have).  If  the disk were given to me I would use ddrescue under Linux to clone the disk (which could then show if the disk is faulty and pull off as much raw data as possible) and then use appropriate tools like testdisk and photorec to try recover data off the copy.

Answer (score 1):

When an external drive starts playing up, the first thing I do is to replace the housing and usb interface along with the cable. I have fixed many just by changing the USB cable alone - Be careful as there are some USB cables that are charge only and are unmarked. Make sure the cable works with another USB HDD first. Cheap cables which are not charge only sometimes cause a voltage drop which makes reading the disk sporadic. I find the thicker and shorter the cable the better.

USB HDD Caddys as they are more popularly known, can be picked up cheaply and replace the old circuitry used to get the disk to connect to the computer via USB.

Another tip is to use a Linux live CD - Ubuntu, for instance - which I have always found to mount partitions on faulty disks more successfully than windows and osx.

A free and highly recommended utility is testdisk, but fully read instructions before using (https://www.cgsecurity.org) - It does take it's time, but is worth the wait if successful.

Beyond this though, you enter the world of data recovery which is a difficult area of IT to navigate. Most HDD manufacturers have a recovery department and although not the cheapest - they will know the disk more than other companies.

It all depends on the price you wish to pay - It can go up to 4 figures.